# creating OPTION element and functions

Tags: javascript

I'm building a **Currency Converter** app in JavaScript, and after creating a `populateCurrencies` arrow function, I want to create an `OPTION` element for each item in the `currencies` array, and call the `populateCurrencies` function inside the already declared `startApp` function.  How do I do this?

Comment: We can't help without seeing your existing code...

Comment: function populateCurrencies () {
          return ()
        }

Comment: thats what i have at the moment i've tried severals code from little research i did, but non is worked yet

Answer (score 0):

To create an `option` element, use the [`Option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) constructor:

```
var option = new Option(text, value); // value is optional, defaults to matching text
```

...or [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement):

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = value;
option.textContent = text;
```

Live Example:

```js
var select = document.getElementById("the-select");

select.options.add(
  new Option("Option 1", "value1")
);

var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = "value2";
option.textContent = "Option 2";
select.options.add(option);
```

```html
<select id="the-select" size="3"></select>
```

Comment: ok, thanks sir, worked well, what about how to implement and call the 'populateCurrencies' function which i've created these option elements under

Comment: @prince - That's probably too broad a question for SO's Q&A format. But if it isn't, it would be a separate question. Questions on SO have to be quite well-targeted and standalone.

Comment: ok, well, just would like to know a good call function format that works as all i tried dont seem to work